# Get coordinates of scatter points on a graph

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

Is there a way to get the pixel cordinates of the points in QCPDataMap ? or is there a way to extract the cordinates of all the scattered points in a graph ?

Comment: This question has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/19893615/3113410

Answer (score 0):

Use `QCpAxis::pixelToCoord` of xAxis and yAxis to convert graph coordinates to px.

If you need global coordinates, use `QWidget::mapToGlobal` after that.