# QCustomPlot Interact with a single point on a graph

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am using `QCustomPlot` and have a multiple graphs plotted on the screen, i want to be able to click and point and then be able to get the data or coordinates etc of the point that I clicked on, I know this is possible for the entire plot itself using `QCP::iSelectPlottables`but is this possible for just an individual point or has anyone found a work around to make this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way to do that. At least there is no such functionality in QCustomPlot.

But you can create class representing single point (derived from `QCPItemEllipse`, for example) and move it with mouse.

I've got similiar functionality in my (not released yet) software, so look and learn... It also can move with shift-modifier (changing only one coordinate of initial position). Plus it changes cursor when it moves to item (and border of item it moves to).

#### plotpoint.h

```
class PlotPoint : public QCPItemEllipse
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PlotPoint(QCustomPlot *parentPlot, int halfSize = 5);

    QPointF pos() const;
    const QColor &color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &color);
    void startMoving(const QPointF &mousePos, bool shiftIsPressed);

public slots:
    void setVisible(bool on);

signals:
    void activated(); ///< emitted on mouse over
    void disactivated(); ///< emitted when cursor leave us

    void moved(const QPointF &pos);
    void stoppedMoving();

public slots:
    void move(double x, double y, bool signalNeeded = true);
    void movePx(double x, double y);
    void setActive(bool isActive);

private slots:
    void onMouseMove(QMouseEvent *event);
    void stopMoving();
    void moveToWantedPos();
    void onShiftStateChanged(bool shiftPressed);

private:
    QCPItemTracer *mCenterTracer;
    QPointF mGripDelta;
    QPointF mInitialPos;
    bool mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate;
    QList<QCPAbstractItem *> mHelperItems;
    QPointF mLastWantedPos;
    QTimer *mMoveTimer;
    QPointF mCurWantedPosPx;
};
```

#### plotpoint.cpp

```
PlotPoint::PlotPoint(QCustomPlot *parentPlot, int halfSize)
    : QCPItemEllipse(parentPlot)
    , mCenterTracer(new QCPItemTracer(parentPlot))
    , mGripDelta()
    , mInitialPos()
    , mLastWantedPos()
    , mMoveTimer(new QTimer(this))
    , mCurWantedPosPx()
{
    mCenterTracer->setStyle(QCPItemTracer::tsNone);

    topLeft->setParentAnchor(mCenterTracer->position);
    bottomRight->setParentAnchor(mCenterTracer->position);
    topLeft->setType(QCPItemPosition::ptAbsolute);
    bottomRight->setType(QCPItemPosition::ptAbsolute);

    topLeft->setCoords(-halfSize, -halfSize);
    bottomRight->setCoords(halfSize, halfSize);

    setSelectable(true); // plot moves only selectable points, see Plot::mouseMoveEvent
    setColor(QColor(qrand()%256, qrand()%256, qrand()%256, 100));
    setPen(QPen(Qt::black));
    setSelectedPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));

    mMoveTimer->setInterval(25); // 40 FPS
    connect(mMoveTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(moveToWantedPos()));
}

QPointF PlotPoint::pos() const
{
    return mCenterTracer->position->coords();
}

const QColor &PlotPoint::color() const
{
    return brush().color();
}

void PlotPoint::setColor(const QColor& color)
{
    setBrush(color);
    setSelectedBrush(color);
}

void PlotPoint::startMoving(const QPointF &mousePos, bool shiftIsPressed)
{
    mGripDelta.setX(parentPlot()->xAxis->coordToPixel(mCenterTracer->position->key()) - mousePos.x());
    mGripDelta.setY(parentPlot()->yAxis->coordToPixel(mCenterTracer->position->value()) - mousePos.y());

    mInitialPos = pos();
    mLastWantedPos = mInitialPos;
    mCurWantedPosPx = QPointF();
    mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate = shiftIsPressed;

    mMoveTimer->start();

    QCPItemStraightLine *horizontal = new QCPItemStraightLine(parentPlot());
    horizontal->setAntialiased(false);
    horizontal->point1->setCoords(mInitialPos.x(), mInitialPos.y());
    horizontal->point2->setCoords(mInitialPos.x() + 1, mInitialPos.y());
    parentPlot()->addItem(horizontal);

    QCPItemStraightLine *vertical = new QCPItemStraightLine(parentPlot());
    vertical->setAntialiased(false);
    vertical->point1->setCoords(mInitialPos.x(), mInitialPos.y());
    vertical->point2->setCoords(mInitialPos.x(), mInitialPos.y() + 1);
    parentPlot()->addItem(vertical);

    static const QPen linesPen(Qt::darkGray, 0, Qt::DashLine);
    horizontal->setPen(linesPen);
    vertical->setPen(linesPen);

    mHelperItems << vertical << horizontal;

    if (!mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate) {
        vertical->setVisible(false);
        horizontal->setVisible(false);
    }

    connect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(mouseMove(QMouseEvent*)),
            this, SLOT(onMouseMove(QMouseEvent*)));

    connect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(mouseRelease(QMouseEvent*)),
            this, SLOT(stopMoving()));

    connect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(shiftStateChanged(bool)),
            this, SLOT(onShiftStateChanged(bool)));

    parentPlot()->grabKeyboard();
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);
}

void PlotPoint::setVisible(bool on)
{
    setSelectable(on);  // we are movable only when visible
    QCPItemEllipse::setVisible(on);
}

void PlotPoint::stopMoving()
{
    disconnect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(mouseMove(QMouseEvent*)),
            this, SLOT(onMouseMove(QMouseEvent*)));

    disconnect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(mouseRelease(QMouseEvent*)),
            this, SLOT(stopMoving()));

    disconnect(parentPlot(), SIGNAL(shiftStateChanged(bool)),
            this, SLOT(onShiftStateChanged(bool)));

    mMoveTimer->stop();
    moveToWantedPos();

    if (!mHelperItems.isEmpty()) {
        while (!mHelperItems.isEmpty()) {
            QCPAbstractItem *item = mHelperItems.takeFirst();
            mParentPlot->removeItem(item);
        }

        mParentPlot->replot();
    }

    parentPlot()->releaseKeyboard();
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();

    emit stoppedMoving();
}

void PlotPoint::move(double x, double y, bool signalNeeded)
{
    mLastWantedPos.setX(x);
    mLastWantedPos.setY(y);
    if (mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate) {
        double x1 = parentPlot()->xAxis->coordToPixel(x);
        double x2 = parentPlot()->xAxis->coordToPixel(mInitialPos.x());
        double y1 = parentPlot()->yAxis->coordToPixel(y);
        double y2 = parentPlot()->yAxis->coordToPixel(mInitialPos.y());
        if (qAbs(x1 - x2) < qAbs(y1 - y2)) {
            x = mInitialPos.x();
        } else {
            y = mInitialPos.y();
        }
    }

    mCenterTracer->position->setCoords(x, y);

    parentPlot()->replot();

    if(signalNeeded) {
        emit moved(QPointF(x, y));
    }
}

void PlotPoint::movePx(double x, double y)
{
    move(parentPlot()->xAxis->pixelToCoord(x),
        parentPlot()->yAxis->pixelToCoord(y));
}

void PlotPoint::setActive(bool isActive)
{
    setSelected(isActive);
    emit (isActive ? activated() : disactivated());
}

void PlotPoint::onMouseMove(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    mCurWantedPosPx = QPointF(event->localPos().x() + mGripDelta.x(),
                              event->localPos().y() + mGripDelta.y());
}

void PlotPoint::moveToWantedPos()
{
    if (!mCurWantedPosPx.isNull()) {
        movePx(mCurWantedPosPx.x(), mCurWantedPosPx.y());
        mCurWantedPosPx = QPointF();
    }
}

void PlotPoint::onShiftStateChanged(bool shiftPressed)
{
    if (shiftPressed != mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate) {
        mIsChangingOnlyOneCoordinate = shiftPressed;
        foreach (QCPAbstractItem *item, mHelperItems) {
            item->setVisible(shiftPressed);
        }
        move(mLastWantedPos.x(), mLastWantedPos.y());
    }
}
```

#### (part of) plot.cpp

```
void Plot::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && mPointUnderCursor) {
        mPointUnderCursor->startMoving(event->localPos(),
                                       event->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ShiftModifier));
        return;
    }

    QCustomPlot::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void Plot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QCustomPlot::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    if (event->buttons() == Qt::NoButton) {
        PlotPoint *plotPoint = qobject_cast<PlotPoint*>(itemAt(event->localPos(), true));
        if (plotPoint != mPointUnderCursor) {
            if (mPointUnderCursor == NULL) {
                // cursor moved from empty space to item
                plotPoint->setActive(true);
                setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
            } else if (plotPoint == NULL) {
                // cursor move from item to empty space
                mPointUnderCursor->setActive(false);
                unsetCursor();
            } else {
                // cursor moved from item to item
                mPointUnderCursor->setActive(false);
                plotPoint->setActive(true);
            }
            mPointUnderCursor = plotPoint;
            replot();
        }
    }
}

void Plot::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift) {
        emit shiftStateChanged(true);
    }
    QCustomPlot::keyPressEvent(event);
}

void Plot::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Shift) {
        emit shiftStateChanged(false);
    }
    QCustomPlot::keyReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Sorry for almost no comments in code. I'm just too lazy for Russian to English translation.

I hope you'll get everything anyways.

Comment: Thanks thats great no problem for no comments i can work it out, thanks again!

Comment: Oh, wait. I've got your question incorrectly. You've asked about getting their coordinates on mouse over, not about moving them with mouse etc. If you don't need moving them with mouse, better do what I've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19893615/726243. Presented method (one item per point) is overkill then.

Comment: I'm not sure you are answering the posters question.

Answer (score -1):

great contribution from  @Obey-Kun, I'd like further discussion if anyone is interested in, especially Kun:)

(1) the basic idea is to

- create an Ellipse item `PlotPoint`,
- along with it there are 2 straightline items
  `horizontal`&`vertical`(for orthogonal moving)
- and one tracer item `mCenterTracer`(center of ellipse, for connecting
  Mouse Action).

(2)according to the plot.cpp(part), I imagine the mechanism might be:

- **press** the leftButton, (to confirm there is one point that can be moved)
- **move** the mouse.(to move the point through tracer)
- **release** the leftButton.(to place the point at last wanted position)

However, I am confused with logic in the

> void Plot::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)

. It looks like a *hover detection procedure*, because everything is done under `Qt::NoButton`.the user move the mouse(with no buttons pressed) to detect whether the mouse is on a plotPoint, if so, transfer `*plotPoint` to `*mPointUnderCursor`. then Press then Move then Release.

Is there anything that I miss?