# Link custom data to the QCustomPlot data

Tags: qcustomplot

Is there a possibility to link user data to the graph data in [QCustomPlot](http://qcustomplot.com/)?
Or at least, is it possible to get X/Y of selected item in graph?
I want to display images captured at the evets visualised by graphs.

Comment: To get x/y values on mouse move see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140446/display-the-plot-values-on-mouse-over-detect-scatter-points).

Comment: @A.Sarid looks like it could help. Will check tonight and write back. Thanks!